# Showing a limit is 1

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $m(n) = \min \{ m : 2^mm^{3/2} \geq n \}$. I want to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(n)/ \log_2(n) = 1$. I have been able to show that the limsup of this limit is at most 1. How can I show the other direction? I'm sure the minimality of $m(n)$ has to be used somwhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
m(n)= \min\left\{m : m+\frac 3 2\log_2(m)\ge\log_2(n)\right\}.
$$
Firstly, it is clear that $m(n)\le\log_2(n)$. Now, set
$$
a_n:= \log_n(\log_2(n)^{3/2})= \frac 3 2\cdot\frac{\log_2(\log_2(n))}{\log_2(n)},
$$
which tends to zero. With $m=(1-a_n)\log_2(n)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
m+\frac 3 2\log_2(m)
&= \log_2(n) - \log_2(n^{a_n}) + \log_2((1-a_n)^{3/2}\log_2(n)^{3/2})\\
&< \log_2(n) - \log_2(n^{a_n}) + \log_2(\log_2(n)^{3/2})\\
&= \log_2(n) + \log_2\left(\frac{\log_2(n)^{3/2}}{n^{a_n}}\right)\\
&= \log_2(n).
\end{align*}
So, $m(n)\ge (1-a_n)\log_2(n)$. Alltogether, $1-a_n\le\tfrac{m(n)}{\log_2(n)}\le 1$, which yields the claim.